# Should the khateeb deliver the Friday khutbah in Arabic?

Tags: arabic, jumuah, khutbah

In my neighborhood, the Friday khutbah is delivered only using Arabic. There are other khateebs that use both Indonesian (or other languages) and Arabic. As far as I know, they replace the sermon by two cycles, one for each language.

**Question:** Can the khateeb deliver the Friday khutbah in a language other than Arabic?

Comment: Are you asking if the *khatib* (the man who gives the Friday khutbah) has to wear Arabic clothes, or if he should speak Arabic?

Comment: he shouldn't speak Arabic but whether the khatib should gives the Friday khutbah in Arabic?

Answer (score 3):

If the majority of worshippers are Arabic speakers, then the Khutba should be in Arabic. If not, there should be a khutba in the language most commonly understood between them. The importance of a Khutba is to guide the believers/ worshippers in Islam; how can they be guided if they do not understand the language?

The Quran states that Allah sent messages to people in their own language. In Surat Ibrahim 14:4:

> 4. "We sent not a messenger except (to teach) in the language of his (own) people, in order to make (things) clear to them. Now Allah
>      leaves straying those whom He pleases and guides whom He pleases: and
>      He is Exalted in power, full of Wisdom."

If Allah sent His messengers in the languages of their respective peoples, then it would follow that the guidance of a Khutba, on a lesser scale than the revelations and guidance of prophets/ messengers, should likewise be in the language of the khateeb's audience. Or in the case of mixed-language audiences, the predominant language, provides the khateeb himself speaks it.

Another point illustrates that what is most important is that people understand the message, more than the language itself in which it is delivered. From Surat Fussillat 41:44:

> 44. Had We sent this as a Qur'an (in the language) other than Arabic, they would have said: "Why are not its verses explained in detail?
>       What! (a Book) not in Arabic and (a Messenger) an Arab?" Say: "It is a
>       Guide and a Healing to those who believe; and for those who believe
>       not, there is a deafness in their ears, and it is blindness in their
>       (eyes): They are (as it were) being called from a place far distant!"

This aya illustrates that because Arabic was the language of Prophet Mohammad and his immediate community, the Quran was sent in Arabic, just as previous revelations were sent in the languages of the receiving community. And Allah knows that this book is a guide to all nations, many of whom do not speak or understand Arabic. But in modern times, translations are more accurate, printing and scholarship are more prevalent, and at the same time the original is preserved unlike prior messages. Since we keep the original, translations can always refer back to it for accuracy and study. A Khutba, on the other hand, is given to Muslims to enhance their understanding of Islam, and help explain both Quran and hadeeths; since the Quran makes it clear that what is important is understanding and clarity, and that even for divine revelations Allah could send them in any language, how much more permissible such direct explanations in non-Arabic languages could be.

Even though the Quran is in Arabic, and it is important for Muslims to learn Arabic to better study the Quran, this does not mean the Khutba must necessarily be in Arabic. The message of Islam can be understood in any language. Understanding is the most important thing in this case.

Comment: Give citations and references from fatawa books, might accept your answer

Comment: I added Quran references above rather than fatwas, because I feel it is more authoritative. Many fatwas are derived from the Quran.  Thank you, jazak Allah khairan.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/112041

Answer (score 1):

❶ - Arabic is the language of Islam, and the Khutbah is part of Islam - and it is absolutely essential not to lose motivation for learning arabic in it's pure form. The Qur'an is only Arabic:

> وكذلك أنزلناه قرآنا عربيّا وصرفنا فيه من الوعيد لعلهم يتقون أو يحدث
>   لهم ذكرا  20:113. And thus We have sent it down as a Qur'ân in Arabic,
>   and have explained therein in detail the warnings, in order that they
>   may fear Allâh, or that it may cause them to have a lesson from it (or
>   to have the honour for believing and acting on its teachings).

❷ - However, having said that (and hopefully imparting the absolute importance of arabic), since the purpose of the Khutbah is to teach the Qur'an, it would be wise to speak in the language of the people as well (without excluding arabic). This is derived from the following ayah:

> ...ولو جعلناه قرآنا أعجميّا لقالوا لولا فصلت آياته أأعجمي وعربي 
>   41:44. And if We had sent this as a Qur'ân in a foreign language other
>   than Arabic, they would have said: "Why are not its Verses explained
>   in detail (in our language)? What! (A Book) not in Arabic and (the
>   Messenger) an Arab?"...

In other words, the importance of language in allowing the audience to understand. And Allah knows best.